# Building HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build HTML in my javascript file this way.I need to add one more classname to my class attribute. But this classname is a javascript variable. I am not sure how to add this variable so that javascript interpolates this.

```
  function build_html(sku)
  {
     //need to add sku as my classname here
     tmpString += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" class=\"cart sku\">ADD TO CART</a>";
  }
```

TIA

Comment: This is done with very very basic JavaScript manipulation. If you don't know how to do that, you shouldn't be coding JavaScript just yet.

Comment: Use `+`. `"Something "+ variable +" something"`

Comment: As MadaraUchiha mentioned, it is one of the very basic tasks one should be able to perform. Maybe a little more practice in coding JavaScript is needed before you tackle some real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the + operator to concatenate strings:

```
  function build_html(sku)
  {
     //need to add sku as my classname here
     tmpString += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" class=\"cart " + sku + "\">ADD TO CART</a>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate your html parts to add class name in your html,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/BRxkv/)**

```
tmpString = "";
classVar = "cart sku";
tmpString += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" class=\""+classVar +"\">ADD TO CART</a>";
```